# Tried to upgrade pip, but error 'WinError 5' showed up

Tags: python, windows, module, pip

I've found a problem with pip and can't do anything with it anymore.
I'm on a Windows 7 computer and have a Dutch language (maybe it will occur problems with reading)

I did use pip version 8.1.1, but there's a newer version, 9.0.1. I installed it using 'pip install --upgrade pip' and he's doing pretty well so it uninstalled the previous version of pip and then the problem came. Now I can't use pip as well. When I try to install or upgrade my system says: 'ImportError: No module named pip'.

I had this problem somewhere in 2016 and never found an answer, so I installed Python again on my computer. I hope there's a better way to do this instead of install whole Python and all those modules again.

So for me is this a bit strange, I hope anyone know this problem and knows a way to fix this. Beneath I'll show up the texts in the command prompt.

**Code:**

```
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' comm
and.

D:\PythonProjects\Python Crash Course\learning_log\ll_env\Scripts>pip install --
upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 8.1.1
    Uninstalling pip-8.1.1:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pascal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\shutil.py", l
ine 538, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
OSError: [WinError 17] Het systeem kan het bestand niet verplaatsen naar een and
er station: 'd:\\pythonprojects\\python crash course\\learning_log\\ll_env\\scri
pts\\pip.exe' -> 'C:\\Users\\Pascal\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-0hagtsau-uninstal
l\\pythonprojects\\python crash course\\learning_log\\ll_env\\scripts\\pip.exe'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\pythonprojects\python crash course\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packa
ges\pip\basecommand.py", line 209, in main
  File "d:\pythonprojects\python crash course\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packa
ges\pip\commands\install.py", line 317, in run
  File "d:\pythonprojects\python crash course\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packa
ges\pip\req\req_set.py", line 726, in install
  File "d:\pythonprojects\python crash course\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packa
ges\pip\req\req_install.py", line 746, in uninstall
  File "d:\pythonprojects\python crash course\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packa
ges\pip\req\req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
  File "d:\pythonprojects\python crash course\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packa
ges\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 267, in renames
  File "C:\Users\Pascal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\shutil.py", l
ine 553, in move
    os.unlink(src)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Toegang geweigerd: 'd:\\pythonprojects\\python cra
sh course\\learning_log\\ll_env\\scripts\\pip.exe'

D:\PythonProjects\Python Crash Course\learning_log\ll_env\Scripts>pip freeze > r
equirements.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pascal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\runpy.py", li
ne 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\Pascal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\runpy.py", li
ne 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\PythonProjects\Python Crash Course\learning_log\ll_env\Scripts\pip.ex
e\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'pip'
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how many people will be drawn to this note, however, if you find yourself in the scenario where the pip install, terminal within PyCharm install, Python Package install, etc. methods are not working and you are receiving the errors that pygame is installed in Conda but module not recognized in PyCharm; it is most likely due to conflicting Python versions having been installed as PyCharm and Conda are both IDEs and you can have overlapping versions of Python installed.

If this is the case, you will need to uninstall all of the versions of Python and Anaconda along with PyCharm.  Then once reinstalled, if PyCharm doesn't recognize itself as a Python Interpreter, then add an interpreter and run as a virtual environment.  At this stage, you should be able to use the python packages section to install PyGames without issue.  You may be able to get by without uninstalling other IDEs however I find that a full purge is full proof.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This is related to disk drives on Windows. Pip downloads the new files to your current drive (`D:`) and then tries to move them over to the system files (on `C:`) and fails.

(See https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2824)

Could you run

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

or is `pip` completely gone?

If it's gone then you would have to re-install it. Maybe re-installing all of Python is easier although probably more time consuming.

Comment: Could that directory be a virtualenv maybe?

Comment: That makes sense, but it's not currently active.

Comment: To ensure the installed system Python is upgraded, the OP should first change out of that directory (e.g. ``cd /d C:\``) to avoid running python.exe from the virtual environment. Then run `python -m ensurepip --verbose --default-pip` and `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`. If `python` can't be found at that point, run `path %PATH%;C:\Users\Pascal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35` to temporarily add the installation directory to the search path.

Comment: I've tried it another day again and now it's working. I didn't do anything different, it stays pretty weird how it reacts and I can't explain it.